# AD DNS: Point subdomain to external shared hosting

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

When creating my domain I didn't realize until computers were joined to it that my AD domain is example.com and my organization's website is also example.com, but is hosted on a remote shared web hosting server.

Now whenever you type example.com into the browser it pulls up the DC's default page, not the remote server.

Can I forward all requests to extweb.example.com to our remote server? A CNAME doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: do people on the internet use example.com or www.example.com?

Answer (score 1):

The CNAME will not work, because it will still point to your domain name, which will be resolved as your DC.

You could possibly make another a-record for your company website, if your webserver allows for it.

```
A = alternate.example.com -> [webserver ip]
```

edit: typo

Comment: This is correct. Use an A record, not a CNAME.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options here.

Option 1:
Rename your domain with a subdomain like ad.yourdomain.com, with the NetBIOS set as yourdomain.

Option 2:

You will have to set DNS records to point to www.yourdomain.com as the www is not present in your DC, then place shortcuts on everyone's computer for the website pointing at www.yourdomain.com.

Option 3

I know its not the correct way of handling things but you could always install IIS on your domain controllers and redirect all trafic to your website.

Hope this helped